# fixed rolling window

Tags: r, fixed, rolling-computation

I want to construct a fixed rolling window in r. Say I have a dataset like this:

```
      Apple Microsoft     Amazon      Tesla
2000 0.91903890 0.5454254 0.22267026 0.41857974
2001 0.13638076 0.7640585 0.56990815 0.04490846
2002 0.19977390 0.9170585 0.04391331 0.72987722
2003 0.70627675 0.2583974 0.03485766 0.35594681
2004 0.08069703 0.2085965 0.19865918 0.30194120
2005 0.03334810 0.7955248 0.75876036 0.28129544
2006 0.94652374 0.6095904 0.98855677 0.36792881
2007 0.90060660 0.3144541 0.78201742 0.02731390
```

I know that the following function will give me an expanding window:

```
 all.cov.matrix <- lapply(1:nrow(stocks), function(y) cov(stocks[1:y,]))
```

To get a fixed window with four periods inside, I have tried the following function:

```
library(zoo)     
all.cov.matrix <- apply(rollapply(1:nrow(stocks), 4, c), 1, function(ix) cov(stocks[ix, ]))
    # However, this returns one big matrix, that is not what I am looking for. 
    # Ideally I want to get the following results:
     cov(stocks[1:4,]) # 1 period
     cov(stocks[2:5,]) # 2 period and so on
```

I want each of the matrices to be stored seperately in `all.cov.matrix`, thus in thix example `all.cov.matrix`should store 5 different matrices.

Comment: Error: could not find function "rollapply"

Comment: @AndreElrico should work now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `apply(..., margin = 2, ...)` to get the columnar covariance. However, I wouldn't recommend `apply`. You can use `lapply` instead, i.e.

```
library(zoo)
lapply(as.data.frame(t(rollapply(1:nrow(stocks), 4, c))), function(i) cov(stocks[i,]))
```

Another way to write this (as per @G.Grothendieck comment),

```
r <- rollapplyr(stocks, 4, function(x) c(cov(x)), by.column = FALSE)
lapply(split(r, row(r)), matrix, 4)
```

Comment: @Sotos thanks, I tried your suggestion and it seems to work the way I wanted

Answer (score 3):

If your expanding window example is close to what you want, you may be able to make it work with some slight adjustments to have the "window" roll the way you want:

```
all.cov.matrix <- lapply( 2:(nrow(stocks)-2),
                          function(y) {
                              cov(stocks[(y-1):(y+2),])
                          } )
```

The way you had `1:y` means that the window always starts at `1`, while `y` increases for each iteration, meaning the window expands. Changing that to `(y-1):(y+2)` means that both the start and end point of your window move along with `y`, always making a window of size `4`.

To be careful not to go beyond the bounds of the data, we also need to change to `X` vector in `lapply` (the first parameter) such that the edges of the window stay within the data.

Comment: when I tried your suggestion, it returned NULL when I wanted to look at the matrices

Comment: To make it simple: `lapply(4:nrow(stocks), function(i) cov(stocks[(i-3):i,]))`

Comment: I've checked @rosscova's answer, it returns the same results as Sotos's solution.